# BWA fails to locate index genome

Tags: indexing, bioinformatics, genome

I know this question has been asked before. I have searched through the threads and nothing has made a ton of sense to me. Admittedly, I am a newbie at bioinformatics so maybe the answer is clear to someone with more experience.

I am trying to use BWA to align reads to a reference genome and keep the discarded reads, as I am looking for potential pathogen DNA (RNA, really) that could have been infecting the host.

I have created, I think correctly, an index of the reference genome. I have the following files:

`_genome.fa`

`_genome.fa.amb`

`_genome.fa.ann`

`_genome.fa.bwt`

`_genome.fa.pac`

`_genome.fa.sa`

I wanted to align paired-end reads to that index and keep the discards. That code is:

`module load swset/2018.05`

`module load gcc/7.3.0`

`module load bwa`

`bwa mem ~/correctpath/_genome.fa correctfilename_R1_001.fastq correctfilename_R2_001.fastq -a > sample_bwa.sam`

I continue to get the error:

`[E::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] fail to locate the index files`

I'm 99.% sure I have the file paths correct. I may have loaded the wrong BWA version. I may have created indexes incorrectly. Or maybe there is something obviously wrong in my bwa mem code.

Again, I've tried to read through other similar posts, but nothing has made a ton of sense to me. Which is probably my fault.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: are you absolutely sure that fasta file and index files are in `~/correctpath/` and have the name that you're using? Are they all accessible in read mode? Which command did you use to index the genome? And finally, are you sure you used the same version of bwa indeed?

Comment: Your commands seems OK. If you are only 99% sure you got the correct path, check for it, because this is where you are getting trouble. Try to `ls ~/correctpath/_genome.fa*` and check that all those files you told us are listed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll quadruple check the path (it wouldn't be the first time I had some silly typo I didn't notice until I looked at it for the 1,000th time). I'll also check bwa versions. Our institution just switched over to a new computing cluster, so it's possible I did use different versions. For indexing, I just used `bwa index _genome.fa`  It's good to know the code looks correct, that makes my troubleshooting strategy a bit simpler. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A very late response, but it seems you're missing the _genome.fai file. The fasta.fai *is* the fasta index and is needed to map the reads.Here's more info on it.

- https://www.biostars.org/p/98885/
- https://www.biostars.org/p/375837/

I would recommend (if you haven't or didn't!) running the following samtools command:

```
samtools faidx path/to/_genome.fa
```

I ran into a similar problem, and this did appear to fix it.